# Missing Wayland requirements for glamor GBM backend ('wl_drm' not supported)

Tags: xorg, xserver, wayland

When starting Xwayland to listen on TCP:

```
Xwayland :1 -listen tcp -ac &
```

...I get some errors like:

```
glamor: 'wl_drm' not supported
Missing Wayland requirements for glamor GBM backend
Failed to initialize glamor, falling back to sw
```

I've installed all of the dependencies that I think Xwayland needs...mesa, libdrm, intel driver, a.s.o.

How can I find out what is still missing here?